# Makefile won't compile anything other than "kernel.c"

Tags: makefile, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compiling, osdev

I've been trying to compile an OS however whenever I attempt to compile it using the make file it only compiles "kernel.c" and I can't seem to figure out why. I need help to figure what's wrong. I've tried everything I could possibly do to fix it at least from my knowledge.

Here's the code:

```
PROJECT_DIR= ..
CXXFLAGS= -ggdb3 -O0 -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib 
CFLAGS=-std=c17
CSRCFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS= -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib
IMG_PATH= ../
BUILD_BACK_TWO= ../../../build
CFILES= $(wildcard *.c)
OFILES= $(CFILES:.c=.o)
GCCPATH=C:/CrossCompilers/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-mingw-w64-i686-aarch64-none-elf
CFLAGSSTART= -ffreestanding -c
CFLAGSEND= -O2 -Wall -Wextra
GCCFLAGS= -Wall -O2 -ffreestanding -nostdinc -nostdlib -nostartfiles
GCCPATHAARCH= $(GCCPATH)/aarch64-none-elf/bin
GCCPATHBIN= $(GCCPATH)/bin
ASMCFLAGS= -f elf32 -F dwarf -g -w+all
ASM= -s

# Location of the files
THIS_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
SRC = $(PROJECT_DIR)/src
UI_IMAGES = $(PROJECT_DIR)/images/ui
OBJ_DIR = $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/objects
ASMSOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.s)
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c)
UISOURCES = $(wildcard $(UI_IMAGES)/*.png)
OBJECTS  = $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.s, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/$(ARCHDIR)%.o, $(SOURCES))
OBJ_KEEP = objects_keep

#Headers
HEADERS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/inc
INCLUDE = -I$(HEADERS)

#File settings
KERNEL_NEEDED=kernel8.img
BASE_KERNEL=base_kernel.img
IMG_NAME=edited_reality


$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.s
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo COMPILING $^
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-as -c $^ -o $@
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo COMPILING $^
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -ffreestanding $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -O2 -Wall -Wextra
$(OBJ_DIR)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo COMPILING $^
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -ffreestanding $(INCLUDE) $(CFLAGS) -c $^ -o $@ -O2 -Wall -Wextra

BUILD: $(OBJECTS)
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    @echo COMPILING $^
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-gcc -nostdlib -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME).elf -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib $(OBJECTS) $(INCLUDE) -lgcc
    $(GCCPATHBIN)/aarch64-none-elf-objcopy $(IMG_NAME).elf -O binary $(KERNEL_NEEDED)


clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm -rf $(IMG_NAME).elf
    rm -rf $(IMG_NAME).img

start:
    @echo Starting
    mkdir $(OBJ_DIR)
    @echo .
    @echo .
    @echo .

.PHONY: clean start BUILD
```

EDIT: I couldn't figure it out so what I'm doing is just writing a one file C++ program that will compile everything else because that is so much easier (for some reason).

Anyways thanks everyone.

Comment: If you are just compiling one file there isn't much point to using a Makefile at all.  You might as well use a shell script that just contains the exact, single command to run.  Still, there should be some way to figure out why it's only compiling one file and MadScientist has given you some useful info about how to debug and how to ask a better question.

Comment: @DavidGrayson well the C++ program that compiles them is one file not the OS that's why I created the C++ program to make it easier to compile the entire thing but I am now having a multiple definition of "_start" problem now.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear whether you mean it runs the compiler one time then stops, or whether it runs the compiler many times but always on the same file.  When asking for help please cut and paste the command you typed and the output you got (or the useful parts if there's a lot of it), and describe what is wrong and what you wanted to happen.

But, I think this is just a typo:

```
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/$(ARCHDIR)%.o, $(SOURCES))
```

Note here you use `$(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c` when you mean `$(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/%.c`.

You can add things like `$(info $(OBJECTS))` to see the value of various variables (or run `make -p`).

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately that was not the only problem because the assembly objects didn't have that typo but they were still excluded or it just stopped I really don't know what happened.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand your comment.  If you still need help, please see my first paragraph (about providing enough info) and last paragraph (about how to debug the makefile) and edit your question with further details about exactly what is wrong.

Comment: So I figured out what the problem is just not how to fix it...
It will only compile the source directory c files (not even the source directory s files) because the rest aren't in the variable OBJECTS but I added them in so they should be I used a += and everything but it doesn't work.



Edit: By the way sorry it took me so long to respond I've been trying to fact check my theory.

Comment: Sorry but I've given all the help I can with the information you've provided.  If you want further help you'll need to edit your question, correct typos in the makefile by cutting and pasting exactly what's in your makefile, then show the command you invoked and the output you got and explain what you expected.  You should also use the `$(info ...)` method as I mentioned above, or use `make -p`, to find the exact contents of the variables that you are using (the OBJECT and SRC\* variables) and cut and paste that as well.  Then we can help.

Comment: Well, one problem I see is that you're assigning the variable SOURCES twice, without `+=`: `SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)` then `SOURCES = $(wildcard $(SRC)/$(ARCHDIR)/*.c)`